# Spring Kafka Listener - Transaction not working properly

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-kafka

I am running the latest version of spring boot app with spring Kafka and MySQL as database and used KafkaChainedTransactionManager for transaction synchronization.

I want to update the same entity object by a particular listener. so when the multiple messages are coming to the topic at a time for updating the same object, the transaction is not waiting until the transaction commits for the same object. so the data in becoming inconsistent.

I have tried using Pessimistic lock-in JPA repository query with no luck.

Listener where the data inconsistency happening when the multiple messages are receiving at the same for updating the same object

```
// method 
@Autowired
private ProcessIndexRepository  processIndexRepository;

@Transactional(readonly=false)
@KafkaListener(id = "update_process", topics = "update_process")
 public update(@Payload String message){

ProcessModel processModel= JsonUtil.toObject(message,ProcessModel.class);
// from repository it will get old data instead of updated data 
 ProcessIndex process= processIndexRepository.findByProcessId(processModel.getId()).get();

   if(processModel.getName()!=null){
      process.set(processModel.getName())
}
if(processModel.getAge()>0){
     processModel.setAge(processModel.getAge())
}

processIndexRepository.save(process);

}
```

Kafka sender config

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaSenderConfig{

    @Value("${kafka.servers}")
    private String kafkaServers;

    @Value("${application.name}")
    private String applicationName; 

    @Bean(value = "stringKafkaTransactionManager")
    public KafkaTransactionManager<String, String> kafkaStringTransactionManager() {
        KafkaTransactionManager<String, String> ktm = new KafkaTransactionManager<String, String>(stringProducerFactory());
        ktm.setNestedTransactionAllowed(true);
        ktm.setTransactionSynchronization(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.SYNCHRONIZATION_ALWAYS);
        return ktm;
    }
    @Bean(value = "stringProducerFactory")
    @Primary
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> stringProducerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServers);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);   
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 100);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, true);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String> defaultKafkaProducerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
        defaultKafkaProducerFactory.setTransactionIdPrefix("sample-trans-");
         return defaultKafkaProducerFactory;
    }
    @Bean(value = "stringKafkaTemplate")
    @Primary
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> stringKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(stringProducerFactory(),true);
    }
    @Bean(name = "chainedStringKafkaTransactionManager")
    @Primary
    public ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<String, String> chainedTransactionManager(JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager, DataSourceTransactionManager dsTransactionManager) {
        return new ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<>(kafkaStringTransactionManager(), jpaTransactionManager, dsTransactionManager);
    }    
}
```

Kafka receiver config

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaReceiverConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.servers}")
    private String kafkaServers;

    @Value("${kafka.groupId}")
    private String groupId;

    @Value("${kafka.retry.maxAttempts}")
    private Integer retryMaxAttempts;

    @Value("${kafka.retry.interval}")
    private Long retryInterval;

    @Value("${kafka.concurrency}")
    private Integer concurrency;

    @Value("${kafka.poll.timeout}")
    private Integer pollTimeout;

    @Value("${kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset:earliest}")
    private String offset = "earliest";

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Bean
    public RetryPolicy retryPolicy() {
        SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(retryMaxAttempts);
        return simpleRetryPolicy;
    }
    @Bean
    public BackOffPolicy backOffPolicy() {
        FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(retryInterval);
        return backOffPolicy;
    }

    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate(){
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy());
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy());
        return retryTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(concurrency);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(pollTimeout);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
        factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, offset);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean(name = { "jsonConsumerFactory" })
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> jsonConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean(name = { "kafkaJsonListenerContainerFactory" })
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Object>> kafkaJsonListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(jsonConsumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(concurrency);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(pollTimeout);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
        return factory;
    }
```

data source config

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.sample.entity.repository")
public class DatasourceConfig {


    @Bean(name = "dataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }   
    @Bean(name = "datasource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("dataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("datasource") DataSource ds) throws PropertyVetoException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(ds);
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.sample.entity.domain"});
        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }
    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager dsTransactionManager(@Qualifier("datasource") DataSource ds) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(ds);
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
        return jpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("datasource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }    
}
```

property file(Kafka config)

```
kafka.servers=localhost:9092
kafka.groupId=xyzabc
kafka.retry.maxAttempts=3
kafka.retry.interval=300000
kafka.concurrency=10
kafka.poll.timeout=1000
```

When updating the same object it should wait until the transaction commits then only the JPA repository should pick the updated object and update newer things

Comment: Probably not related but you shouldn't need or use `@Transactional` on the listener;  inject the chained tx manager into the container factory and the container will start both transactions. I am not familiar with JPA so I can't answer that.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are multiple updates coming from the producer in a single transaction or are you losing updates in the listener? Is the database becoming temporarily inconsistent or permanently inconsistent?

Comment: Please specify "latest version of spring boot app" for the record.

Comment: @K.Nicholas I am loosing updates in the listener. Due to this data is becoming permanently inconsistent. When I am producing multiple message to update the same object..like update name ,age,address,,etc then the transaction does not wait until the previous transaction  commits, so its picking old object from database  and the data is becoming  permanently inconsistent

Comment: @jordiburgos Spring boot version is 2.1.4

Comment: You must be sending a lot of updates all at once. Why do that? Why not send them all at once? You should post that code, is it just writeMessage, writeMessage, writeMessage? If you're not getting transaction demarcation then your getting messages asynchronously?

Comment: @K.Nicholas, I am sending the updates from different methods(scenario). so sometimes all updates are coming at a  time. First of all my doubt is if the one entity object from the database table in a transaction then how another thread can have access to modify same object? is there any transaction boundaries problem in my code or in MySQL(InnoDB)?

Comment: The database should have a row lock but you also have the object cached in memory with JPA/Hibernate as well as modification in an unsynchronized code block so the issue may revolve around that. You need a test case as in multiple threads writing so that you can demonstrate the problem and test possible fixes. That requires a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which you will have to write first before I would look further unless someone else wants to try writing it on the hopes they can reproduce the issue you describe.

Comment: I would expect that you would use kafka transactions on the sender side which I think should address such an issue. You could also put synchronization around or inside your kafka `update` listener but you will want to be careful with that, so perhaps try java synchronization starting before the JPA read and after the JPA save should do the trick or at least tell you if that is the problem area. These are basic concurrency issues so you should become more familiar with them if you are working in a multithreaded environment as is typical in Java EE applications.

Answer (score 0):

Your main culprit is threading below line.

```
kafka.concurrency=10
```

When multiple threads are beginning and committing the transaction for same object you should synchronize that code block else you may not be able to maintain the consistency. It will happen for any code where simultaneous updates are happing for same records.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid race conditions by using the partition key.